WPF DataGrid Virtualization – Strange error after scrolling
I'm facing a problem and can't get any further.
I hope you can help me.
Short explanation:
I have a DataGrid (VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true") and a search bar. When I type something into the search bar, the list is filtered accordingly and the search text is highlighted using an AttachedProperty.
The highlighting is done by splitting the TextBlock text into several inlines. A corresponding background color is then set in the inlines that contain the search text.
Works fine:

Problem:
As soon as I scroll down and up again, the elements that have left the visible area suddenly contain the same text as the 2nd element. The same thing happens at the end of the list. The strange thing is, when I scroll down and up again, some of the text is correct again.

I checked the Grid's LoadingRow event and saw that the Row that comes into the visible area contains the correct data in the DataContext, but the texts in the TextBlocks have not updated.
My thought was that perhaps the binding was broken by manipulating the inlines, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

If EnableRowVirtualization is set to false, it works, but unfortunately virtualization is absolutely necessary because the list can basically have n entries, the current estimate is up to 5000.
At the beginning of the method HighlightTextBlock(TextBlock) the call  txtBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty) returns the corresponding data but at the end of the method after the Inlines are set, txtBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty) returns null.
Did this break the binding? That would explain why in GridOnLoadingRow the DataContext contains the new data but the TextBlocks still contains the old.
I hope you can help me, below is the code for my test project.
Formular.xaml
<DataGrid
          Grid.Row="0"
          local:Highlighter.Filter="{Binding Filter, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="true"
          ColumnWidth="100"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DisplayedItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          RowHeight="30"
          SelectionMode="Single" />

<WrapPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <Label Content="Filter: " />
    <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Filter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</WrapPanel>

Formular.xaml.cs
public partial class Formular : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, args) => { };
    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
    
    public ICollectionView DisplayedItems { get; set; }

    private string filter;
    public string Filter
    {
        get => this.filter;
        set
        {
            this.filter = value;

            this.DisplayedItems.Refresh();
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Formular()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        var listItems = new ObservableCollection<MyListItem>()
        {
            new MyListItem("Alpha", "Mission1"),
            new MyListItem("Beta1", "Mission1"),
            new MyListItem("Beta1", "Mission2"),
            new MyListItem("Beta1", "Mission3"),
            new MyListItem("Beta1", "Mission4"),
            new MyListItem("Beta1", "Mission5"),
            new MyListItem("Beta1", "Mission6"),
            new MyListItem("Beta1", "Mission7"),
            new MyListItem("Beta1", "Mission8"),
            new MyListItem("Beta1", "Mission9"),
            new MyListItem("Beta2", "Mission2"),
        };

        this.DisplayedItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listItems);
        this.DisplayedItems.Filter = this.FilterCallback;
    }
    
    public bool FilterCallback(object obj)
    {
        var item = (MyListItem) obj;

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Filter)
               || item.Name.ToUpper().Contains(Filter.ToUpper())
               || item.MissionName.ToUpper().Contains(Filter.ToUpper());
    }
}

Highlighter.cs
public static class Highlighter
{
    private static string filter;

    static Highlighter(){}

    #region Filter
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Filter", typeof(string), typeof(Highlighter), new PropertyMetadata("", PropertyChangedCallback));

    public static void SetFilter(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FilterProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetFilter(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj?.GetValue(FilterProperty);
    }

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => DoAction(d)));
    }
    #endregion

    private static void DoAction(DependencyObject d)
    {
        filter = GetFilter(d);
        if (filter == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var grid = (DataGrid)d;
        grid.LoadingRow += GridOnLoadingRow;

        // Get DataGridRows
        var gridRows = grid.GetDescendants<DataGridRow>().ToList();
        foreach (var row in gridRows)
        {
            HighlightRow(row);
        }
    }
    
    private static void HighlightRow(DataGridRow row)
    {
        // Get TextBlocks
        var txtBlocks = row.GetDescendants<TextBlock>().ToList();
        if (!txtBlocks.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var txtBlock in txtBlocks)
        {
            HighlightTextBlock(txtBlock);
        }
    }

    private static void HighlightTextBlock(TextBlock txtBlock)
    {
        var text = txtBlock.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Check whether the text contains the filter text
        var index = text.IndexOf(filter, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            // Filter text not found
            return;
        }

        // Generate Inlines with highlighting information
        var inlines = new List<Inline>();
        while (true)
        {
            // Text from beginning to filter text
            inlines.Add(new Run(text.Substring(0, index)));

            // Text that corresponds to the filter text
            inlines.Add(new Run(text.Substring(index, filter.Length))
            {
                Background = Brushes.Yellow
            });

            // Text from filter text to ending
            text = text.Substring(index + filter.Length);

            // Check whether the remaining text also contains the filter text
            index = text.IndexOf(filter, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                // If not, add remaining text and exit loop
                inlines.Add(new Run(text));
                break;
            }
        }

        // Replace Inlines
        txtBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        txtBlock.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
    }

    private static void GridOnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataContext = (MyListItem) e.Row.DataContext;

        var newData = $"{dataContext.Name}_{dataContext.MissionName}";
        var oldData = string.Join("_", e.Row.GetDescendants<TextBlock>().Select(t => t.Text).ToList());
    }
}

MyListItem.cs
public class MyListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, args) => { };
    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion

    
    public string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string missionName;
    public string MissionName
    {
        get => missionName;
        set
        {
            this.missionName = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyListItem(string name, string missionName)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.MissionName = missionName;
    }
}

I don't know what i can do.
I checked the other answers but I have the impression that nothing is suitable for my problem.

If it's "incremental searching" you're trying to implement, one method is to only show the eligible records (returned); in which case high-lighting is somewhat redundant.

FWIW, I do incremental searching on the "backing store"; e.g. "paragraphs" of text. If I find paragraph(s) that match, I do what you do: Create "inlines". But I create the TextBlock also; and load all of them into a StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer. (No "property notification" ... just load the "text  blocks" into a viewable container). "Code" is fast (i.e. searching); and only loading the results, makes the UI fast.

Yes, I only show the search results, but the searched text needs to be highlighted, that's a requirement.
And also using a DataGrid because we have some derived classes that we use everywhere.

My suggestion was to "generate" a  result set; not "fiddle" with the existing UI. You can have the "source" in one "panel"; and the results in another (panel).
